# netsh ssl cert binding multiple url windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, windows-7-x64, netsh

I'm trying to bind 2 different urls for the same IP with ssl cert. This would be a piece of cake in IIS with SNI. However, in my case the 2 urls are exposed as Windows Service in a Windows 7 SP1. It appears that netsh sslcert hostnameport option is only available in Windows Servers and not in Windows 7. I tried to copy the netsh exe from windows server to windows 7 - as expected it did not work.

So some how I have to make 2 urls corresponding to windows service work with SSL on same windows 7 machine - is there any options? I cannot change the port - that's not an option unfortunately...

Comment: It works if you can have two IP addresses that resolve to your machine - but you probably already know that. I've just done it with loopback addresses 127.0.0.2 and 127.0.0.3 with a distinct SSL cert bound to each (Windows 7 SP1).